# Classic ASP: Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400' Expected statement

Tags: html, asp-classic, bootstrap-4

Not good in classic ASP. I need to add popUp when clicking on Delete or Recover (x and circled arrow). Here is ASP code without popUp:

```html
i = 0
   while not rs.eof
    i = i +1
    'a.AccountID,a.Deleted,MSPdisabled,MSPppAccountID ,a.Name,a.Description,a.Notes,a.WebSite,at.AccountType
     Dict.SetKey = "dataTableRow_" & i
     arrValues = split(varValues,",")
     j = 0
     sDelete = "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=/portal3/#ajax-config/?rID=Deleted&ClientID=" & request.querystring("ClientID") & "&type=" & sType & "&Type2=" & varType2 & "&ID=" & rs(trim(varType2)) & varCabinetAction &  "&Action=Del"
     'if varClientID <> "" then sDelete = sDelete & "&ClientID=" & varClientID
     sDelete = sDelete & varRandomString & "><span class=""glyphicon glyphicon-remove"" title=""Delete"" id=""deleteItemFromFolder""></span></a>"
     <%
     ^
     response.write("")
     %>
     
     sRecover = "&nbsp;<a href=/portal3/#ajax-config/?rID=Deleted&type=" & sType & "&Type2=" & varType2 & "&ID=" & rs(trim(varType2)) & "&Action=Recover"
     if varClientID <> "" then sRecover = sRecover & "&ClientID=" & varClientID
     sRecover = sRecover & varRandomString & "><span class=""glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"" title=""Recover""></span>"


     Dict.SetField j, sDelete & sRecover
     for each value in arrValues
      j = j +1
      'response.write value
      Dict.SetField j,rs(value).value
     next
     Dict.Update 
    rs.movenext
   wend         

   arrFields = split(langOptions&"," & varFields,",")
   sFieldOptions = ""
   for each aF in arrFields
    if sFieldOptions <> "" then sFieldOptions = sFieldOptions & ","
    sFieldOptions = sFieldOptions & "1"'always nowrap
   next
   arrFieldOptions = split(sFieldOptions,",")'wrap/not wrap
   
   response.write funDataTable(Dict,arrFields,arrFieldOptions,arrOptions)
   'END DICTIONARY
   Set Dict = Nothing
   '######################################################################
  else
   response.write "<div class=""alert alert-info""><strong>"&langNONETOPURGERECOVER&"</strong></div>"
  end if

 end if
```

I tried to add bootstrap coding. Here how it looks like injected:

```html
i = 0
   while not rs.eof
    i = i +1
    'a.AccountID,a.Deleted,MSPdisabled,MSPppAccountID ,a.Name,a.Description,a.Notes,a.WebSite,at.AccountType
     Dict.SetKey = "dataTableRow_" & i
     arrValues = split(varValues,",")
     j = 0
     sDelete = "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=/portal3/#ajax-config/?rID=Deleted&ClientID=" & request.querystring("ClientID") & "&type=" & sType & "&Type2=" & varType2 & "&ID=" & rs(trim(varType2)) & varCabinetAction &  "&Action=Del"
     'if varClientID <> "" then sDelete = sDelete & "&ClientID=" & varClientID
     sDelete = sDelete & varRandomString & "><span class=""glyphicon glyphicon-remove"" title=""Delete"" id=""deleteItemFromFolder""></span></a>"
     
     sRecover = "&nbsp;<a href=/portal3/#ajax-config/?rID=Deleted&type=" & sType & "&Type2=" & varType2 & "&ID=" & rs(trim(varType2)) & "&Action=Recover"
     if varClientID <> "" then sRecover = sRecover & "&ClientID=" & varClientID
     sRecover = sRecover & varRandomString & "><span class=""glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"" title=""Recover""></span>"
     
     <%
     response.write("
     <div class="widget-body no-padding">
  <div class="smart-form">
   <footer>
    <input id="feedbackForDeleteSettings" name=submit value="<%=langResetSettings%>" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger" type=submit data-toggle="modal" data-target="#resetChanges">
    <input id="saveCustomTheme" name=submit value="<%=langUpdateAboveSettings%>" class="btn btn-primary" type=submit data-id="userCustomization">     
    <div class="modal fade" id="submitChanges" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="submitChanges" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
       </button>
       <h5 class="modal-title">You successfully updated the changes!</h5>  
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="deleteItemFromFolder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteItemFromFolder" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
         <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h5 class="modal-title">You successfully removed all custom changes.
         </br>
         Please, reload the page.
        </h5>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

   
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>
     ")
     %>



     Dict.SetField j, sDelete & sRecover
     for each value in arrValues
      j = j +1
      'response.write value
      Dict.SetField j,rs(value).value
     next
     Dict.Update 
    rs.movenext
   wend         

   arrFields = split(langOptions&"," & varFields,",")
   sFieldOptions = ""
   for each aF in arrFields
    if sFieldOptions <> "" then sFieldOptions = sFieldOptions & ","
    sFieldOptions = sFieldOptions & "1"'always nowrap
   next
   arrFieldOptions = split(sFieldOptions,",")'wrap/not wrap
   
   response.write funDataTable(Dict,arrFields,arrFieldOptions,arrOptions)
   'END DICTIONARY
   Set Dict = Nothing
   '######################################################################
  else
   response.write "<div class=""alert alert-info""><strong>"&langNONETOPURGERECOVER&"</strong></div>"
  end if

 end if
```

But all the time I get "Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0400'

Expected statement

/portal3/ajax-config/config.asp, line 9697

<%
^
". 
I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: What's on line 9697 of config.asp?  The error message suggests that there's something wrong with your syntax, eg you've forgotten to close quotes or brackets.

Comment: Line 9697 was "<%"

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the problem. It was stupid. I thought That something was missing, but it turned out that something instead was extra. There was no need in this sign "<%". It should be just "response.write("")"